# Spring-Social-Facebook - only one login per app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-social-facebook

I just built a simple (spring-boot) web app that will be able to access facebook data following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/) guide. The app works great, it lets me login and fetch data from facebook.

The problem occurs when I try to login with multiple accounts. For example I open Google Chrome first. I go to localhost:8080/facebook and I get redirected to facebook. I login there and now I get redirected to my App and the information that I got from facebook are shown.

Next, I try doing the same in Mozilla Firefox. I open Mozilla, go to localhost:8080/facebook and I expect to get redirected to facebook, so I can login. But the redirect never happens, the app acts like I am already logged in on facebook and it shows my facebook info (the info from the account that I logged in from Google Chrome). It's important to note that if go directly to facebook.com, I am not logged in there.

Is this a normal behavior for spring-social? Is it possible to make login with multiple accounts ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Main class:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestingAuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(TestingAuthApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.controllers;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.PagedList;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Post;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class FacebookFetcher {


    Facebook facebook;
    ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

    @Inject
    public FacebookFetcher(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/facebook", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }

        model.addAttribute("facebookProfile", facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());

        System.out.println("HEHEHE");
        PagedList<Post> feed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
        model.addAttribute("feed", feed);
        User currentUser = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();
        System.err.println(currentUser.getName());
        System.err.println(currentUser.getAbout());
        System.err.println(currentUser.getAgeRange());
        System.err.println(currentUser.getBio());
        System.err.println(currentUser.getBirthday());
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you solved this? I am facing the same issue right now.

Comment: Well I stopped using spring social. I just did a login with facebook (using OAuth) and then used the facebook token to directly fetch data from the facebook API using RestTemplate.

Comment: I was thinking the same, it seems that Spring isn't suitable for use with Facebook that way anyway. Thanks!